# wxWidgets, wxAUI, wxDockIt: who uses it?

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets

I am looking for a library which will help me create applications with a native look and feel for Linux, Mac and Windows (mainly Windows).

I don't know a lot about the different libraries (GTK+, Qt, wxWidgets, etc.) but as I have understood, wxWidgets respects the OS API for rendering GUI controls, and it still works for older OS's (which I will be targetting too).

Now my question is: how widely used is wxWidgets? Did Microsoft use it for their office software, like Word and Excel for example?

I have tried installing wxDockIt (which I believe is not part of wxAUI?) using MinGW, but it failed. I ran following command (as stated in C:\wxDockit\installation.txt):

```
C:\wxDockit\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc
```

This gives the following output:

```
g++ -c -o mingwd\wxdockit_lib_dockpanel.o -DHAVE_W32API_H  -D__WXDEBUG__ -D__WXM
SW__ -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\lib\gcc_lib\mswd -IC:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\include -I..\.
.\include -W -Wall -O0 -g -mthreads    -MTmingwd\wxdockit_lib_dockpanel.o -MFmin
gwd\wxdockit_lib_dockpanel.o.d -MD ../../src/generic/dockpanel.cpp
../../src/generic/dockpanel.cpp: In member function `bool wxDockPanel::Create(wx
Window*, wxWindowID, const wxString&, unsigned int)':
../../src/generic/dockpanel.cpp:79: error: 'class wxWindow' has no member named
'GetTitle'
../../src/generic/dockpanel.cpp: In member function `wxPlacement wxDockPanel::Te
stForPlacement(int, int)':
../../src/generic/dockpanel.cpp:368: warning: `Inside' is deprecated (declared a
t C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/include/wx/gdicmn.h:490)
../../src/generic/dockpanel.cpp:372: warning: `Inside' is deprecated (declared a
t C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/include/wx/gdicmn.h:490)
mingw32-make: *** [mingwd\wxdockit_lib_dockpanel.o] Error 1
```

And my last question: Does wxAUI or wxDockIt have cross platform support for all three OS's (Linux, Mac and Windows)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't use wxWidgets and, frankly, I would be flabbergasted if they did. It is, or was, however used by quite a few big companies and lots and lots of small(er) ones, see [the website](http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/users.htm) or the [wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSoftware_that_uses_wxWidgets) (which is smaller but, embarrassingly, seems more up to date).

As for wxDockI`, it's an independent project which has nothing to do with AUI (except overlapping with it in what it does) and is definitely not part of wxWidgets. Apparently it's also not being maintained since quite some time if it doesn't compile with ~7 year old wxWidgets version.

If you are looking into starting a project with wxWidgets, you should use AUI which is included in wxWidgets 3.0.